# ASP .NET MVC Core + SignalR: Redirecting from a Hub to a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

##### Question

Is it possible to redirect a user from a SignalR Core Hub to any other location within my application?

I tried using `GetHttpContext` and then invoking `Response.Redirect`, but I get an exception informing that the `Response` has already been started.

##### More context

I use MVC in my application to get a simple controller for routing and for using the MVC cookie-based authentication. Then on successful authentication a user gets redirected by my Controller to a location governed by a SignalR Hub. However, I noticed that in some situation I need to return user to login page based on the information in my Hub.

Does it make sense or maybe I made a mistake while designing my application and need to rework it now?

Comment: Redirect from the client code (document.location.href)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Wiktor Zychla said, we should do these things at client-side, since the server hub's method couldn't redirect the client. You could only write the method at the server and then do the redirect by using the client js.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
    public async Task RedirectPage(string user) {
        // You could send it to a specific user
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("RedirectPageClient", "home/index");
    }
```

Js codes:

```
           connection.on("RedirectPageClient",function(url){
           
              console.log(url);
              window.location.href = url;
      
           });
```

Comment: Got it. I only had to call the Client method synchronously, but adding a `Wait()` at the end did the trick. Thanks.